# How to use autohotkey to place clipboard text into query string of url

Tags: autohotkey

Here is what I want to do:

!f:: Run, browserpath www.example.com?groupid=WANTPASTEDVALUE&exporttype=1&vehicle=34928 return

I want to put the value of the clipboard where WANTPASTEDVALUE is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the contents of the clipboard in a command, use the [built-in special variable, `Clipboard`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm).

```
!f:: Run, "http://www.example.com?groupid=%Clipboard%&exporttype=1&vehicle=34928"
```

Notes: if you include the protocol (`http://` or `https://` in this case) windows will automatically choose your default browser and you can omit the path to the browser. This has the benefit of not forcing a user to use a browser that they don't like, and it's easier to write to boot.

Also, notice that I added quotes. If your clipboard contains a space and you run it *without* quotes, the browser will interpret it as two separate urls, which you certainly don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the clipboard already contains the data, it would be %Clipboard% thus,

```
!f:: Run, browserpath www.example.com groupid= %ClipBoard% &exporttype=1&vehicle=34928
```

When you only have one command on the same line there is no need for a return